# Why do I get index beyond bounds if I fill array in another thread?

Tags: multithreading, ios6, grand-central-dispatch, alassetslibrary

I'm using the assets enumerator block to populate two arrays; one for library assets and one for fullScreen pictures. **_albumAssets** array is used as data source for one **collectionView** and **_albumPics** for my detail **scrollView**. Because I'm adding elements in both arrays from the same block I get poor performance. I thought that adding objects to my arrays directly from the block is ok because the block executes in a separate thread. So I came up with this code, maybe it's a stupid thing to do,I don't know for sure. My performance has increased a lot but sadly now I get the **NSRangeException** so any kind of help or advice is appreciated.  The weird thing is that I get this only sometimes, meaning I present my detail ScrollViewController by tapping on a thumbnail from my **collectionView**. When I start swiping through my images sometimes I get the exception and sometimes not...

```
-(void)enumerateAssetsFromGroup:(ALAssetsGroup *)group
{

    [_albumAssets removeAllObjects];
    [_albumPics   removeAllObjects];

    void (^assetEnumerator)(ALAsset *, NSUInteger, BOOL *) = ^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
    {
        if (result != NULL) {
            [_albumAssets addObject: result];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            ALAssetRepresentation *assetRep = [result defaultRepresentation];
            img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[assetRep fullScreenImage]];
            [_albumPics addObject:img];
        });

    }

        [self.collectionView reloadData];
};

    [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock: assetEnumerator];
}
```

Comment: Might it be possible that _albumAssets contains thumbnails whose pictures have not been loaded yet into _albumPics, since this is done asynchronously? If you then used the index of the 1st array, you would get an NSRangeException.

Comment: @ReinhardMänner Hey, thanks for the reply. If it is so , what can be a potential fix ?

Comment: If this is the problem, you 2 arrays are out of sync. "Asynchronously" means you never know when the data will arrive. So you should show the thumbnails only for pictures that have been loaded already, and are available. You could move your statement [_albumAssets addObject: result]; to the asynchronous block. Both arrays would then be synced, even if the thumbnails would show up later, but then the pictures would be available.

Comment: @ReinhardMänner if this will be done , _albumAssets count will be 0 because it never gets the data

Comment: @ReinhardMänner is there nothing else I can do ? I've moved the statement to the asynchronous block and my images don't show

Comment: I am sorry, but from the code you provided it is hard to say what should be changed. I have the impression that the main problem is that you load the thumbnails fast, but the pictures slowly (asynchronously), and you let the user choose a thumbnail whose picture is not yet loaded. I would show the user only those thumbnails whose pictures are already loaded. Maybe you define an object that represents thumbnail + picture, and show the user only those thumbnails? Then you would have no sync problems. Of course, the user would have less thumbnails to select, but those would have pictures loaded..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://blog.slaunchaman.com/2011/02/28/cocoa-touch-tutorial-using-grand-central-dispatch-for-asynchronous-table-view-cells/) is a tutorial how one can load table view cells asynchronously.
You could thus load your table view cells first with greyed-out thumbnails that cannot be selected, and change the display to normal and make it selectable as soon as the corresponding image has been loaded asynchronously. Then the user had an thumbnail overview about all images, and which of them are already available.